# Joomla 2.5 with Rocket Theme (RT) voxel template loads slowly for first time

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, voxel

I have developed Joomla site using RT voxel template and when pages loads for first time it takes 10 seconds and if i refresh then it loads with 2 seconds for next time in all browser.

What would be the reason for this slow?

Either the template voxel or any other plug-in or component

Thank in advance

Comment: install `yslow` for firefox, and you can see which data is loaded and how long it takes for each component. then make a refresh and you will see what is pulled from the cache, and how long which component takes

Answer (score 0):

Login in admin go to global configuration,set cache to on. By default it is set to off, also most components and modules come with a caching system built in to cache the specific module or component, usually on its dit page under module manager or in its components settings.